# Unable to cURL image. Not sure what to do

Tags: php, curl

We've gotten permission to periodically copy a webcam image from another site. We use cURL functions elsewhere in our code, but when trying to access this image, we are unable to.

I'm not sure what is going on. The code we use for many other cURL functions is like so:

```
$image = 'http://island-alpaca.selfip.com:10202/SnapShotJPEG?Resolution=640x480&Quality=Standard'    

$options = array(
                    CURLOPT_URL => $image,
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
                    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
                    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10
                );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        $cURL_source = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

This code doesn't work for the following URL (webcam image), which is accessible in a browser from our location: http://island-alpaca.selfip.com:10202/SnapShotJPEG?Resolution=640x480&Quality=Standard

When I run a test cURL, it just seems to hang for the length of the timeout. `$cURL_source` never has any data.

I've tried some other cURL examples online, but to no avail. I'm assuming there's a way to build the cURL request to get this to work, but nothing I've tried seems to get me anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If I open it in the browser, it takes forever as well, until the request fails. I don't think there is a way to make cUrl download unreachable resources. I would choose a more stable resource to test with. Then, try using `wget` or command line `curl` to see if the server can actually reach it (might be firewalled). If that works, try using PHP.

Comment: if you var_dump the `$cURL_source` what does it show? Have you tried `curl_error($ch);` to see what error comes up?

Comment: GolezTrol, I can access the URL in a browser. Sometimes it does take a while but not always. @Javad $cURL_source never has anything in it and I get "couldn't connect to host" from curl_error($ch)

Comment: @user955664 if you want to get the image why don't you use `file_get_contents` function?

Comment: @Javad I already had the cURL code used elsewhere on the site for similar purposes. I just tried `file_get_contents` and it didn't work either.

Comment: Then the issue might be from the link server; for example it may enabled CSRF protection which does not allow the outside request; or it might be sensitive to used user-agent in header of the request. If you have fiddler or even FF firebug, you can check what is the exact header params if you hit the url in browser; then set same header params in your request by CURL, hopefully it helps

Comment: @user955664 Your script ran for me and downloaded the image just fine. You're missing a semicolon at the end of the line with your URL, though. I assume that's a copy-paste error?

Comment: @user955664 `file_get_contents()` runs fine too: `var_dump(strlen(file_get_contents("http://island-alpaca.selfip.com:10202/SnapShotJPEG?Resolution=640x480&Quality=Standard"))); => int(30560)` … May I assume that it just blocks maybe requests from your server IP (range?)?

Comment: @user955664 Do you probably need to use a proxy to connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you fetch the URL from the server where this code is running?  Perhaps it has firewall rules in place?  You are fetching from a non-standard port: 10202.  It must be allowed by your firewall.

I, like the others, found it easy to fetch the image with curl/php.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any problems with your code. You can get error sometimes because of different problems with network. You can try to wait for good response in loop to increase the chances of success.

Something like:

```
$image = 'http://island-alpaca.selfip.com:10202/SnapShotJPEG?Resolution=640x480&Quality=Standard';
$tries = 3; // max tries to get good response
$retry_after = 5; // seconds to wait before new try

while($tries > 0) {
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $image,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $cURL_source = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if($cURL_source !== false) {
        break;
    }
    else {
        $tries--;
        sleep($retry_after);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As it was said before, I can either see any problem with the code. However, maybe you should consider setting more timeout for the curl - to be sure that this slow loading picture finally gets loaded. So, as a possibility, try to increase CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to weird big number, as well as corresponding timeout for php script execution. It may help.
Maybe, the best variant is to mix the previous author's variant and this one.

Answer (score 1):

I tried wget on the image URL and it downloads the image and then seems to hang - perhaps the server isn't correctly closing the connection.

However I got file_get_contents to work rather than curl, if that helps:

```
<?php
$image = 'http://island-alpaca.selfip.com:10202/SnapShotJPEG?Resolution=640x480&Quality=Standard';
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
$src = 'data: '.mime_content_type($image).';base64,'.$imageData;
echo '<img src="',$src,'">';
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's not working? Your code is working fine for me (after adding the missing semicolon after `$image = ...`).

The reason it might be giving you trouble is because it's not actually an image, it's an MJPEG. It uses an HTTP session that's kept open and with a multipart content (similar to what you see in MIME email), and the server pushes a new JPEG frame to replace the last one on an interval. CURL seems to be happy just giving you the first frame though.